# Mac Address Timestamp python

Tags: python, network-programming, timestamp

I have this silly question. I analyze data packets with scapy. And there is a variable inside the packet, it's called timestamp (TSFT) , which is the time that the packet was constructed. So i grab that vairable (packet[RadioTap].TSFT) but I do not know if the value is in nanoseconds or in microseconds.

Could anyone inform me ? I haven't seen it anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does it look like?

Comment: here is a sample : 50306148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in microseconds. From http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/TSFT :

> Value in microseconds of the MAC's 64-bit 802.11 Time Synchronization
>   Function timer when the first bit of the MPDU arrived at the MAC. For
>   received frames only.

Answer (score -2):

The timestamp is in seconds.

You can import datetime in python and use its fromtimestamp method to get it in a easier to read format like so.

`import datetime
ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1305354670.602149)
print ts
2011-05-14 02:31:10.602149`

Hope this helped.

Comment: I work in MAC ADDRESS timestamp so I dont think this will help

Comment: @user2220115 This has nothing to do with the OP question.